# way to override @RedisHash value in configuration

Tags: spring-data-redis

I'm using a framework which is based spring-data-redis, and the framework was using @RedisHash to set value the redis key uses. Is there a way to override the value set in @RedisHash?

I'm tring to use KeyspaceSettings to do that, but it seems not working. I've noticed the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.repositories.keyspaces) says "@RedisHash has the highest priority", is it the truth?

> However, the annotated keyspace supersedes any other configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can choose the name of the hash adding a name parameter like this:

```
@RedisHash("name_hash")
```

Comment: The problem was that I cannot touch the source code of the Class (in this case, RedisRepositoryStateMachine), and in the context, it seems that overrides the RedisHash name was harmless, but I just do not know how to do it.